# Tempos de execução discrepantes em programação paralela

Tags: c, thread

Fiz um código paralelo em C com o intuito de verificar seu tempo de execução.
Foi tratado:

- Threads;
- Mutex;
- Falso Compartilhamento;
- Sincronização.

Ao executar o `time` do Linux com a execução do código, em geral foi possível computar no seguinte tempo:

```
Resultado da soma no modo concorrente = 36028797153181696  

real    0m0.340s  
user    0m1.300s  
sys     0m0.000s
```

Porém, a cada +- 5 execuções dessas, ocorria um tempo drasticamente diferente:

```
Resultado da soma no modo concorrente = 36028797153181696  

real    0m1.863s
user    0m5.584s
sys     0m0.000s
```

O que faltou tratar?
O que significam os tempos `real`, `user`, `sys`?

Segue o código que calcula a soma de elementos de 1~N

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define QTD 268435456 //1024//16384 //8192
#define QTD_N 4

unsigned long long int soma = 0;
unsigned long int porcao = QTD/QTD_N;

struct padding{
    unsigned long long int s;//soma parcial;
    unsigned int i,start,end; 
    unsigned int m; // identificador de parcela
    char p[40];
};

pthread_mutex_t mutex_lock;


void *paralelo(void *region_ptr){
    struct padding *soma_t;
    soma_t = region_ptr;
    soma_t->s = 0;    
    soma_t->start = soma_t->m * porcao + 1;
    soma_t->end = (soma_t->m + 1) * porcao; 
    for(soma_t->i = soma_t->start; soma_t->i <= soma_t->end ; soma_t->i++){
        soma_t->s += soma_t->i;
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_lock);
    soma += soma_t->s;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_lock);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void){ 
    pthread_t thread[QTD_N];
    struct padding soma_t[QTD_N];
    int i;
    void *status;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_lock,NULL);
    for(i = 0 ; i < QTD_N ; i++){
        soma_t[i].m = i;
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, paralelo, &soma_t[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < QTD_N ; i++){
        pthread_join(thread[i],&status);
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_lock);

    printf("Resultado da soma no modo concorrente = %lli\n",soma);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Executei o seu código algumas dezenas de vezes e não pude reproduzir a discrepância nos tempos. Pode dar mais detalhes sobre o seu ambiente de teste?

Comment: no Linux: [gcc codigo.c -o executaval -lpthread] para gerar o binário.Depois, faça [time ./executavel] e vai gerar o resultado do código e em seguida os tempos de execução

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sobre o `time`, o resultado é expresso em três tempos:

- `real`: Esse é simplesmente o tempo que você contaria em um relógio (muitas vezes referido como *wall clock*). É a diferença entre a hora de início e a hora de término.
- `user`: Aqui é o total de tempo que o seu processo passou acordado e executando em algum núcleo. Note que se ele estiver sendo executado em mais de um núcleo ao mesmo tempo, conta n vezes. Então esse valor pode ser maior que o  `real`.
- `sys`: Aqui o tempo que o sistema gastou para fazer algo que foi pedido pelo seu processo, como printar coisas na tela ou ler arquivos. É um processamento feito indiretamente.

Sobre a diferença medida durante a execução, ocorre que uma thread encerra seu processamento rapidamente enquanto que as outras três passam mais tempo processando, por algum motivo qualquer. Fica claro aqui:

[image: grafico]

Esse fenômeno parece desaparecer quando o codigo é otimizado pelo compilador antes da execução transformando `soma_t->s` e `soma_t->i` em registros. Dessa forma não há mais leitura e escrita de memoria no loop (ou seja: o problema pode ter algo haver com o cache do processador).

Note que é o sistema que tem o trabalho de decidir quando e por quanto tempo cada thread será executada. O motivo de no seu caso específico isso ter acontecido me escapa, mas é algo comum. O comportamento desse tipo de código não é determinístico, não espere que seja.

Comment: Ao meu ver, parece mais que algum motivo qualquer, pelo fato do tempo variar apenas em algumas execuções e por ter um tempo bem diferente.Fiquei imaginando se não deixei algum detalhe de arquitetura a ser considerado.De qualquer forma, estou satisfeitíssimo com a sua resposta. Obrigado!

Comment: O motivo menos improvável que pude pensar foi randomização do espaço de endereços somado a alinhamento de cache das variáveis da stack. E talvez alguma interferência de outro processo no core. Meio difícil achar uma boa causa. Mas ligar otimização pareceu resolver. Talvez alguém apareça com uma boa explicação depois.